# Mimimum number of guesses

Tags: mathematics, counting

Given the numbers 1 to 1000, what is the minimum numbers guesses needed to find a specific number if you are given the hint "higher" or "lower" for each guess you make? I realize the answer for this particular question is technically 1 if you guess right first off but is there a "general" expected minimum?

Thanks

Comment: binary search problem, probably a duplicate.

Comment: The problem is actually about finding the "maximum minimum". As in:  In the worst case scenario, what is the least number of guesses you need?